# Exporting Output From a Powershell Script to CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, foreach

I found a PowerShell script that looks to be just what I need, but I am having trouble exporting the output to a CSV.  I think it may be the `foreach` portion that is giving the trouble, was wondering if anyone can pinpoint the cause.

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=corp,DC=ourcompany,DC=Com" 
foreach ($G in $Groups)
{
    Write-Host $G.Name
    Write-Host "-------------"
    $G.Members
}
```

Specific error is:

```
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:6 char:2
+ }|Export-csv -path c:\temp\adusers.csv
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement
```

Comment: *I'm having trouble* is not a problem description that is useful unless you explain what *trouble* you're having. We can't pinpoint the cause of a problem you have not specified.

Comment: As the first paragraph states, this Powershell script will not export to a csv.  Specific error is:

At line:6 char:2
+ }|Export -csv -path c:\temp\adusers.csv
+  ~
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement

Comment: That error message explains the problem. It should be in your question where it belongs (and where it should have been when you posted your question). Please [edit] your question to include that information. (When you have a problem that produces an error message, and it's right on your screen in front of you, there is absolutely *no reason* that it shouldn't be in your question here. You're asking us for free help; you should make it as easy as possible for us to give it to you by providing the information you have already.)

Comment: you have to write export-csv together but have a look at [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849932.aspx) there are also usefull examples ;)

Comment: @Eldo.Ob That's clearly a typo or the exception would have been CommandNotFoundException.

Comment: The error message does not match the code you posted. Please show the code that's actually producing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Groups,DC=corp,DC=ourcompany,DC=Com" 
$Groups | Select Name, Members | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\myfile.csv" -Delimiter ";"
```

if you want all attributes just use

```
$Groups | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\myfile.csv" -Delimiter ";"
```

or get your attributes as you like to:

```
$Groups | Select Name, Members, DistinguishedName, Email | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\myfile.csv" -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: Don't forget the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter for `Export-Csv`.  I've never had a situation where I didn't want that.